# Merge and Animate Plot in Maple?

Tags: plot, merge, maple

I have a section of maple code in which I am rendering two separate plots I then store these plots in variables `plot1` and `plot2`.

**For Example:**

```
plotAnimation = NULL:
for f to 10 do
  plot1 := plot( [points1], view=[-12..12,-12..12], color=red, axes=none, scaling=constrained );

  plot2 := plot( [points2], view=[-12..12,-12..12], color=green, axes=none, scaling=constrained );

  plotAnimation := plotAnimation, [plot1, plot2]
end do;
display(plotAnimation, insequence=true);
```

I would like to merge these two plots and at the same time animate them. For some reason I keep getting errors when I do this. I have a procedure that is used to assign the `plot1` and `plot2` variables a plot(curves()) using basic 2D plot function in this case `plot`. But I keep getting errors I am not sure what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need minor corrections: Each plot pair needs to be combined with **display**.

```
plotAnimation = NULL:
for f to 10 do
  plot1 := plot( [points1], view=[-12..12,-12..12], color=red, axes=none, scaling=constrained );

  plot2 := plot( [points2], view=[-12..12,-12..12], color=green, axes=none, scaling=constrained );

  plotAnimation := plotAnimation, display([plot1, plot2])
end do;
display([plotAnimation], insequence=true);
```